# Using the Proper ReLU derivative prevents learning

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, relu

I'm trying to implement the backpropagation with ReLU as the activation function.
If I am not mistaken the derivative of that function is 1 for x > 0 and 0 for x < 0.
Using this derivative the network does not learn at all. 
Searching for other examples I found that most ignore the 1 for X > 0 part and just leave it at x, which leads to much better results.
I wonder why that is the case.

To make sure I there are no other mistakes, here is the code for training a 1 input, 1 output no hidden Neuron Network. 
I use the mean squared error as a error function

```
import random

x = random.uniform(0, 1)
y = random.uniform(0, 1)
w = random.uniform(0, 1)
lr = 0.1

for i in range(500):
    z = x * w
    yP = z
    if yP < 0:
        yP = 0
    loss = (yP - y)**2
    print(i, loss)

    grad_y=2.0*(yP - y)
    grad_z = grad_y
    if z < 0:
        grad_z = 0
    else :
        grad_z = grad_y
    grad_w = grad_z * x
    w -= lr * grad_w
```

Please note that is it unlikely it has to do with the size of the network I also tested on a network with 1000 input Neurons, 1 hidden Layer with 100 Neurons and 10 Output Neurons. I used a batch size of 64 and 500 epochs. It had the same problem.

Comment: First of all, try to do backpropagation with bias too. Secondly, the loss should be used as 1/2 (yP-y)^2 for the ease of backpropagation (grad_y doesn't have 2). Lastly, why do you initialize x and y as random numbers here? Since they are random numbers, I don't think there is any function that can be used to connect them.

Comment: I create my inputs and outputs randomly, because it's just a test network and I do not have any real data at hand. The network just learns this one batch over and over again. That should not be an issue as a NN is an arbitrary function approximator. I can change the error function to use 1/2 but that does not solve the issue. The weird thing is that it learns properly once I use x = x for the positive part of the derivative opposed to x = 1 which would be the proper derivative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realised what a silly mistake I had.
According to the chain rule grad_y should be multiplied with the derivative of ReLU at h which is 0 or 1. This is of course equivalent to just setting it to 0 if the derivative is 0.